# Node issues with SQL Selection inside Object.keys forEach loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This problem has had me banging my head against a wall for the better part of a day. On my nodeJS server-side code, after a condition has been met, the function I'm featuring will be called, and the object.keys loop is used to do a function for each object key. The thing is, the query format that I'm using has been used elsewhere in the script, with no issues, and other parts of the function are done without issues. Through some simple debugging, I've narrowed the issue down to aforementioned SQL query and its lack of functionality, but as the query is the same as it has been used elsewhere with minor tweaks, I'm unsure as to why it doesn't function properly. Below is the NodeJS code. All variables that aren't seen to be defined inside the code snippet are defined elsewhere and are available to use to the function.

```
Object.keys(blackPlayers).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key);
    var userWinnings = blackPlayers[key] * 2;
    con.query("SELECT * FROM _users WHERE id = '" + key + "'", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result) {
            console.log("attempting to get credits");
            newUserCredits = result[0].credits;
            console.log(newUserBalance);
        }
    });
    var newCreditsAfterWinnings = newUserCredits + userWinnings;
    console.log(newCreditsAfterWinnings);
    con.query("UPDATE _users SET credits = '" + newBalanceAfterWinnings + "' WHERE id = '" + key), function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    };
});
```

The top console.log works, it outputs the key from the object, and a different console log that I have since removed also was able to print the userWinnings variable, however, while the query doesn't throw any errors, there is nothing logged to the console from the two lines which say to log to the console inside the SQL query result function, and the script fatally errors when trying to defined the newCreditsAfterWinnings variable, as it says newUserCredits isn't defined, bringing me back to the conclusion the SQL isn't working. I do not know why and have tried reformatting it over and over again to try and make it work, to no avail.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59556837/peculiar-nodejs-issue-with-sql-query-inside-of-an-object-loop)?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(result)` before the `if (result){` conditional? Perhaps `result` is not directly returning a value that will return true for the conditional.

Comment: Don't you need the second `con.query()` inside the callback of the first `con.query()`?  These are asynchronous so to sequence, you have to nest callbacks if using plain callbacks like you are.

Comment: Also, you should never be writing `if (err) throw err;` inside a plain asynchronous callback - never.  That's just wrong and does nothing useful.  None of your code can process that `throw`.  You need to write real error handling code

Comment: FYI, I fixed your code formatting to make it readable.  Please make an effort to properly format/indent your code here when posting a question.

Comment: Woah, there's even more wrong here.  You can't use shared variables for multiple asynchronous calls in a loop.  They will all potentially be trouncing over each other.  Declare your variables with `let` inside the loop so they are unique for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Fixed multiple of the problems mentioned in these comments, unfortunately I have issues where my socket.io won't connect sometimes and it takes 2-3 hours before I am able to connect again so I'll have to test it then. Will update at that point.

Comment: None of the solutions work, still does not work as intended, am going to try some alternative solutions later today and get back with some results.

Comment: Tried making an external function with the same query that takes in the key as a parameter and still nada, moved it back inside the foreach loop and tried console logging just ("hello") after the query statement and it doesn't even log that but doesn't fatally error?